# map many values into a single key in boost::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I don't see a way to map multiple values to one key in a [`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html). My map is declared as:

```
boost::unordered_map< uint16_t, Myclass* > myMap_;
```

I think I could achieve this by storing objects of MyClass in containers, i.e:

```
boost::unordered_map< uint16_t, vector<Myclass*> > myMap_;
```

however unordered_map provides the meanings to manage load factor size, therefore I wonder if it really can't or **maybe it can somehow tie multiple values into a single key**?

```
float max_load_factor() const;
```

Returns: Returns the current maximum load factor.

```
void max_load_factor(float z);
```

Effects: Changes the container's maximum load factor, using z as a hint.

```
size_type bucket_size(size_type n) const;
```

Requires: n < bucket_count()
Returns: The number of elements in bucket n.

---

I know I can use multimap

```
typedef boost::unordered_multimap< int, MyClass*, MyHash<int> > HashMMap;
```

however I wondered if multiple values for a single key are possible somehow with a use of unordered_map.

Comment: So you want to use [`boost::unordered_multimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_multimap.html)? (Or better yet, if your compiler supports C++11 [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap))

Comment: Semantically, an `unordered_map` maps one key to one value. It sounds like you need an `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: `bucket_size()` and `max_load_factor()` reflect how data is hashed internally. It doesn’t have anything to do with how many values are associated with a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C++11 §23.2.5 *Unordered associative containers*

> An unordered associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise, it supports equivalent keys. `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` support unique keys. `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap` support equivalent keys.

If you want more than one value, you'll need to use a multimap (C++11 or from boost), or store a container as the value. A plain `unordered_map` will not do it.